# Use a personal static library in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, static-libraries

I'm working in Visual C++ 2010, Express Edition.

I created a static library, and I would like to be able to use it in every single project/solution I create from now on, by default (or with a single, simple line of code - no changing project options every single time). I don't know for sure, if this is possible, but it sounds like the kind of thing that would be.

I have searched around for a way to do this, but all I found were instructions on using a library in one Project, and that I already managed to do:

- I put both the (library) .lib and the (header) .h file in the project folder,
- added the .lib file in Project Properties->Linker->General->Input->Additional Dependencies,
- *#include*'d the header file.

This way I can use the library with the project, but the files have to be in the same path as the project files, and I have to fiddle with the project's properties. Is there a way to make the library available by default, to any program I create?

Comment: if you create the new project in the same solution, and add dependency  Visual Studio will do this for you. Other than that there is no magical way every project to depend on this one, unless you install it as a system library, but you do not want to do that.

Comment: Edited the question - I would like to use the library in different solutions. I am not looking for magic, only for a option that might exist in VC++ similar to "Additional Dependencies", but that applies to all projects/solutions - or applies only to some, but you can change it's default.

Comment: I am not aware of any limitation of adding the same project in more than one solution. It could be a bit tricky with the directory layout, but it should work. You may consider using SCM to organize your projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add #pragma comment (lib, "yourlibraryname") to your header file.   This forces the inclusion of the library in your project without explicitly linking to it.

For the include directory and library directories, you could create a property sheet.  Store the library and header file in common directory.  Add these directories to the Include and Library directories in the property sheet.  Then include this property sheet in any project that requires use of your library.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would I go about including the property sheet in the projects/solutions? I'm looking into property sheets right now, and from what I understand (which, admittedly, is still not much), including a property sheets requires changing project-specific options, i.e., going through drop-down menus and option windows everytime I create a project/solution. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the new property sheet to each new project.  Right-click in property manager to "Add existing property sheet".  Not sure if this is what you mean by drop-down menus/option windows?

Comment: By "drop-down menus" I meant context menus, such as the Right-click one (couldn't quite rember the name, at the time). As soon as I have some free time, I will look into this method and see if I can make this work. At first glance, it seems like it might not be exactly what I wanted, but could be good enough. I'll let you know the result, and, of course, if it works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I have tried it, and it seems to be working. Instead of #pragma comment(lib, "library"), I added the library directly to the dependencies, in the property sheet, resulting in one less line of code to write (not much, I know, but... yeah). Thank you